# How can I automate printing by selection via filtering in Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, printing, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet with 5 fields, the only important one being the warehouse #. I need to do a separate print job for each warehouse number, but I have 12,000 records and probably a couple hundred different warehouse numbers.

At the moment, I filter for a specific warehouse #, highlight all of them, print by selection. A print job pops out but then I have to do this again for the next warehouse #. Is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do is to use SubTotals. Under Data Subtotal the select At each change in (Warehouse) , Use function ( max) add subtotal to Warehouse. 
Make sure you check, Page Break between groups. then click ok. You can also setup the page to print the headers at each page. Clean up as needed.

Here are some screenshots from the setup. [image]

[image]